# is it possible to run JSLint as commandline in windows with help of node.js?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, command-line, jslint

I mean to run it like this:

```
node.exe lint.js my_js_file.js
```

And then get output to a console.

What do I need to download ? Do I need just to save `http://www.jslint.com/` to disk and then grab some attached js file or I need to look for special version for node.js ?

Answer (score 22):

Install `jshint` globally then you can use it from the command line.

```
npm install -g jshint
jshint testfile.js
```

All this is assuming that you already have `node` and `npm` running on you windows machine.

**Edit**
I just noticed that I responded with an answer for `jshint` instead of `jslint`, the as the other answer points out, they are similar but not the same. My answer holds true for both though.
For `jslint`:

```
npm install -g jslint
jslint testfile.js
```

Comment: Which is a better tool? `jslint` or `jshint`

Comment: @NevinRaj Neither is better per se, It depends on the level of flexibility you want. `jslint` is made by Doug Crockford and is very strict while `jshint` allows you to define some rules. You might also want to check out [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/).

Answer (score 5):

March's answer is for jsHint.  Minor changes for jsLint, with an "L", if that's precisely what you want.

Here's a decent guide for Ubuntu.  Most of it translates:
http://blog.simplytestable.com/installing-jslint-for-command-line-use-on-ubuntu/

So once you've installed node, you can do the following:

```
C:\Users\YourName>mkdir C:\usr\share\node-jslint

C:\Users\YourName>cd C:\usr\share\node-jslint

C:\usr\share\node-jslint>npm install jslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint/-/jslint-0.2.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint/-/jslint-0.2.10.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-1.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-1.0.10.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.4.tgz
jslint@0.2.10 node_modules\jslint
+-- nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
```

Note that I borrowed the path from the Ubuntu directions for my `C:\` drive.  You can put the jslint module wherever you want.  Just ensure that you change the path in the jslint call, below.

Now I can run jslint against any file I want using the jslint module I've installed.  I downloaded [jQuery development 1.11](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js) just for fun, and saved it to `c:\temp\jquery-1.11.0.js`.  So let's jslint it.

```
C:\usr\share\node-jslint>node C:/usr/share/node-jslint/node_modules/jslint/bin/jslint.js c:\temp\jquery-1.11.0.js

c:\temp\jquery-1.11.0.js
 #1 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
    (function( global, factory ) { // Line 15, Pos 10
 #2 Unexpected space between '(' and 'global'.
    (function( global, factory ) { // Line 15, Pos 12
 #3 Unexpected space between 'factory' and ')'.
    (function( global, factory ) { // Line 15, Pos 28
 #4 Use spaces, not tabs.
    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) { //
 Line 17, Pos 1
 ...
```

Etc etc.  I'm in `C:\usr\share\node-jslint`, above, but I've used the full path to `jslint.js`, so I can use the same call anywhere.

And you're linting.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include `jslint` not just `jshint`, thanks for noticing. Also, if you install your modules globally using the `-g` option with `npm install`, the module is added to your PATH and you do not have to use the full path when you want to call the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

1. install Node;
2. run `npm install jshint -g` from CMD
3. add "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\" to "%Path%"